# Feed on a Tensorflow Estimator

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to perform a complicated function approximation in Tensorflow with several layers. The function is going to be trained using a lot of generated data, so I want to be able to generate the data at runtime simply due to the sheer quantity of generated data necessary. I decided to try using an Estimator with a ModelFnOps, but I'm at the point where I'm writing the training loop and I can't seem to find any documentation on using something like `eval(feed_dict=my_feed_dict)` that is shown [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#feeding). The only thing I've found so far has been calling `fit()` on the Estimator, but that requires calling the entire data set (unless I've misunderstood the purpose of that function). Is there any way to feed in single examples or batches within a loop to train an Estimator?

Comment: The estimators can usually take an array or a generating function.

Comment: @drpng How would one implement that? A function that has no parameters and returns a single dict with an input/output pair? There doesn't seem to be any method that can take a function as the input.

Comment: Are you using `tf.estimator.Estimator.train`? It should take a generating function as input.

Answer (score 0):

You can feed in your data via an [input function](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/input_fn). This input function is a  first-class function that gets passed to the estimator (or the eval/train/predict methods).

You can also make use of the [dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/programmers_guide/datasets) to create data feeders and iterators and return the feeder operations in your input functions.